# Python 3 - list slicing - find given element and return slice of list[elem-10:elem+10])

Tags: python-3.x, list, slice

I am dealing with a list of strings.
I want to look up the list for a given elem, and if found, I want to return the slice of list that goes from n indexes before to n indexes after the found element.

```
str_list = ['str1','str2','str3','str4','str5','str6','str7','str8']
for i in str_list:
    for elem in str_list:
        if '5' in elem:
            print(elem in range(str_list[i-2:i+3]))

#expected output
['str3','str4','str5','str6','str7']
```

Comment: Are you looking for `'5'` or `'str5'` or any string containing `'5'`?  You can use `index` for precise string `str_list.index('str5')` or use `next` to get the first index matching some condition `next(i for i, x in enumerate(str_list) if '5' in x)`.  This will return `None` if there is no such string in the list.

Comment: I am looking for all elements containing a certain feature. In the example, all elements containing 5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
str_list = ['str1','str2','str3','str4','str5','str6','str7','str8']

for c,i in enumerate(str_list):
    if '5' in i:
        new = str_list[c-2:c+3]

In [1068]: new
Out[1068]: ['str3', 'str4', 'str5', 'str6', 'str7']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can `enumerate` the list and loop through it, yielding a slice centered on every element that matches your condition:

```
def slices(sequence, radius, condition):
    for i, x in enumerate(sequence):
        if condition(x):
            begin = i - radius
            begin = 0 if begin < 0 else begin
            end = i+radius+1
            yield sequence[begin:end]

print(list(slices(str_list, 2, lambda s: '5' in s)))
# [['str3', 'str4', 'str5', 'str6', 'str7']]
```